# Flussonic Auth Backend API Configuration token generation

Tags: php, flussonic

I am currently encountering challenges with the Flussonic Auth Backend API while attempting to secure our URL. Despite following the documentation closely, we're facing two key issues:

Empty Response:
Our requests to the API at the endpoint

[OUR IP]/streamer/api/v3/auth_backends/Security

consistently result in an empty response from the server. This behavior is unexpected, and we're seeking guidance on resolving this issue.

**Empty Response:**
Our requests to the API at the endpoint [OUR IP]/streamer/api/v3/auth_backends/Security consistently result in an empty response from the server.

**Token Update Delay:**
We've noticed a significant delay in token updates on the server side, taking approximately 1 hour. This delay is impacting our system's performance and responsiveness.

If anyone has experience with Flussonic Auth Backend API or suggestions for server-side configurations and optimizations, I would greatly appreciate your expertise.

In this API we are passing allow as well as deny tokens like this:

Here is the payload we're using:

```
{
    "name": "Security",
    "allow_tokens": ["demoToken"],
    "deny_tokens": ["Test"]
}
```

We're open to any recommendations, tips, or potential solutions to improve our Flussonic Auth Backend API configuration.

Comment: What does the server error_log says?